# Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

In my React Native `0.60.4` app i'm trying to use `react-native-firebase`and i have done everything except `react-native-link` as it's not supported in the latest version of React Native. When i give command `react-native-run-android`,it shows a lot of errors from the node module of `react-native-firebase`. I'm guessing it's happening for some version conflict. Here is the long error :

[image]

Here's my app build/gradle file dependencies:

```js
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+" 
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"
    // implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-functions: 17.0.0"
    // implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics: 16.5.0"
    // implementation " com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.2.1"
    // implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:16.5.0"
    // implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:17.0.0"
    // implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid: 18.0.0"
    // implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:17.0.0"
    // implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:17.0.0"
  
  // Firebase dependencies
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
    implementation"com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0"
   
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    if (enableHermes) {
      def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermesvm/android/";
      debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
      releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
      implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And my android build/gradle :

```js
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.1.0" 
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2')
        classpath( 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0')

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Run npx jetify

From the project root directory, where the node_modules is

Comment: This did it for me after trying to get an existing project from someone else up and running for 3 hours. Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries, happy to hear that you fix it.

Comment: That actually was not the fix, had to start from scratch and tested, but this command is needed anyways.

Answer (score 7):

Simply Reinstall ***React Native Firebase***

```
npm install --save @react-native-firebase/app
```

**After this its 100% works.**

Comment: I have no idea why, but this worked for me.

Comment: Doesnt work for me...has anyone solved this in any other ways ??

Comment: uninstall first(remove firebase/app from node_modules) and then install again, it works

Comment: For me next command that did it after installing rn firebase as mentioned above was to run:
npx jetify

As per answer from @Manoj Alwis

Answer (score 2):

You have update your openjdk with this:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew install --cask zulu11
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just faced this issue as well. Upgrading openjdk from 8 to 11 will get error away.

This script is to install openjdk 11: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1988#issuecomment-1070831039.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the **issue** was the **difference in the versions** of `@react-native-firebase/app` and `@react-native-firebase/firestore` so reinstalling the libraries updated both of them to the latest version, and the issue was resolved

```
yarn add @react-native-firebase/app @react-native-firebase/firestore
OR 
npm install @react-native-firebase/app @react-native-firebase/firestore
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it says that there is a problem in firebase here, but updating the JDK to JDK 11, resolves this issue.

Do use [SDK man](https://sdkman.io/) to manage different Java versions on the same machine.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to **link** react-native-firebase library.
Also, you can refer the documentation for firebase here https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/tree/master/packages/firestore or https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/getting-started

Comment: Doesn't work with yarn add @react-native-firebase/firestore command too. @AbhishekSutariya

Comment: yarn also works with windows.Anyway,i tried with npm install.But still the same.

Comment: After installing it gives this error: Project with path ':@react-native-firebase_app' could not be found in project ':@react-native-firebase_firestore' @AbhishekSutariya